# JRebel and Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, jrebel, eclipse-photon

I can't start an Eclipse configuration with JRebel enabled when using Eclipse Photon M6. Is this known ? I don't get such an error with Eclipse Oxygen.

The error log is here: https://gist.github.com/jeffmaury/2f8afc581ddaa194edf889d17ec39798

Comment: Eclipse Photon will be released on June 27. The next milestone 7 (M7) will be released as preview build this weekend. It looks like JRebel is using internal API of Eclipse causing this issue.

Comment: What application are you running? Is it a standalone application or a webserver?

Comment: The error's stack trace indicates that a change in the Equinox OSGi framework has occurred that broke the way how JRebel instruments certain classes. The error will be fixed soon and I'll let you know when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest [nightly build](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/nightly-build/) and the fix will also be included in the 2018.1.3 release of JRebel.